# Python Zip List Append

Tags: python

EDIT: more info added

How can I 'append' a new list to already zipped list. The main reason for doing this, I need to scan through a dictionary and split any fields with a certain character and add the resulting list to the ziplist.

```
dictionary = {
    'key1': 'testing'
    'key2': 'testing'
    'key3': '6-7-8',
    }
list1 = ['1','2','3']
list2 = ['3','4','5']
ziplist = zip(list1,list2)

for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
    if '-' in value:
        newlist = value.split('-')
        ziplist.append(newlist)

for a,b,c in ziplist:
    print a,b,c
```

Expected output would be

```
1 3 6
2 4 7
3 5 8
```

Using the above code I get the following error.

```
for a,b,c in ziplist:
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I assume the 'newlist' list is not being appended to the ziplist. Why is this not working?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by append? Can you show expected output?

Comment: I don't really think you can. If instead you would create `ziplist` just before the `for` loop `ziplist = zip(array1,array2,newlist)` (assuming `newlist` also has length 3), it would work.

Comment: Not quite. With your current code, `newlist` gets added to the end of `ziplist` as another element rather than merged with the existing elements.

Comment: As @Neftas says... just don't `zip` all the lists until you need them...

Comment: I have added more information in regards to the problem which may help clarify why I wanted to do this. Or perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: it is a bad idea - to change question after you already got a bunch of answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to actually look at what you are creating:

```
>>> array1 = ['1','2','3']
>>> array2 = ['3','4','5']
>>> ziplist = zip(array1,array2)
>>> ziplist
[('1', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('3', '5')]
```

and then

```
>>> newlist = ['7', '8', '9'] # for example
>>> ziplist.append(newlist)
>>> ziplist
[('1', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('3', '5'), ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Clearly, that is not what you want. The most straightforward way, assuming you no longer have access to `array1` and `array2`, is to flatten `ziplist` back out using `zip` again, then add `newlist`, then re-`zip`:

```
>>> flatlist = zip(*ziplist)
>>> flatlist
[('1', '2', '3'), ('3', '4', '5')] # almost back to array1 and array2
>>> flatlist.append(newlist)
>>> ziplist = zip(*flatlist)
>>> ziplist
[('1', '3', '7'), ('2', '4', '8'), ('3', '5', '9')]
```

---

Alternatively, as you don't need the zipped lists in the interim, keep collecting the flat lists throughout and only `zip` at the end:

```
flatlist = [['1','2','3'], ['3','4','5']]

for value in dictionary.itervalues():
    if '-' in value:
        flatlist.append(value.split('-'))

for t in zip(*flatlist):
   print " ".join(map(str, t))
```

Note that you may not have exactly 3 items in each tuple in `ziplist`, so I have removed that assumption.

Comment: Hi. This seems to work for me and I didn't think of creating a 'flatlist' so to speak of all my list first. Thanks for you response. As this worked I didn't bother trying the other methods which I'm sure probably would have given me the result but I found your answer very thorough. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care too much about the internal structure of your merged list, you can just `zip` your additional list onto the existing one. This will have items that are nested tuples, like `((1, 3), 6)`, but you can unpack those as you iterate:

```
for (a, b), c in zip(ziplist, newlist):
    print a, b, c
```

Comment: This worked the best for me, since I was just iterating over the items. This is a cool syntax trick. Much wow. Very python.

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]

ab = zip(a, b)  # [(1, 3), (2, 4)]

c = [5, 6]

abc = zip(*zip(*ab), c)  # [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

I usually use Blckknght's approach, though.